# How to change the color of the JQueryUI Dialog Title?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to change the background color of the JQueryUI Dialog.  I used the following style to change it and it works.  But the problem is it also effect, DatePicker Dialog Title.  I only want to change the Dialog title not DatePicker title.  Could you please advise me how I could change only the Dialog tile color?  Thanks.

```
.ui-widget-header
{
    background-color: #F9A7AE;
    background-image: none;
    color: Black;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can target the `titlebar` directly, the dialog plugin will output HTML similar to the following for the dialog title:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header">
  <span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Basic dialog</span>
</div>
```

(Taken from the Dialog page, [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/))

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-color: #F9A7AE;
  background-image: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass a class to the dialog:

```
$('#foo').dialog({dialogClass: 'myClass'});
```

[See here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass)